# javascript variable not populated correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically, the "rec" variable is correctly filled, but it's not happening with the "email" variable . Why?

This is my code:

```
<textarea id="q" name="q"></textarea>
<button onclick='alert(rec);'>Click</button>
<a id="email" href="#" target="_blank">Email</a>

<script>
    var rec;
    var email;

    $("#q").keyup(function() {
        rec = $('#q').val();
        email = 'www.corriere.it/' + rec;
        $('email').attr("href", email);
    });
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wvsc93d4/3/

Comment: select by id   $('#email')

Comment: Also, I guess, the `href` attribute should start with "http(s)": `email = 'https://www.corriere.it/' + rec;`

Comment: You missed `.href` in `email.href = 'www...'; `. Also, you don't need `$('email').attr(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using the selector correctly, try:

```
$('#email').attr("href",email);
```

Comment: lol damn me... thank you

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `#` selector:

```
$('#email').attr("href",email);
```